# i try Call to a member function save() on array with session data

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I try to make a two step from which first form data stored in session and in second form, I try to save data with data of step 1 which is stored in session. All queries run but laravel only stored the field inputs .
What can I Do?
my second form data stored in database but my first form data goes to null value. 
This is my controller file

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Admissionform;
class AdmissionformController extends Controller
{

    /**
     * Show the step 1 Form for creating a new product.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function createStep2(Request $request)
    {
        $admissionform = $request->session()->get('admissionform');
        return view('front_office_desk.create-step2',compact('admissionform', $admissionform));
    }
    /**
     * Show the step 1 Form for creating a new product.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function createStep3(Request $request)
    {
        return view('front_office_desk.create-step3');
    }
    /**
     * Post Request to store step1 info in session
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function postCreateStep1(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'name' => 'required',
            'dateOfBirth' => 'required',
            'contactNumber1' => 'required',
            'contactNumber2' => 'required',
            'email' => 'required',
            'reference' => 'required',
            'address' => 'required',
            'purpose_of_visit' => 'required',
            'intend_to_apply_for' => 'required',
            'any_applied_file_for_visa' => 'required',
            'acknowledgement' => 'required',
        ]);
        if(empty($request->session()->get('admissionform'))){
            $admissionform = new Admissionform();
            $admissionform->fill($validatedData);
            $request->session()->put('admissionform', $admissionform);
        }
        return redirect('/front_office_desk/create-step2')
                        ->with('success','Product updated successfully');
    }   
    public function postCreateStep2(Request $request)
{
    $request->validate([
        'specialization' => 'required',
        '12institute_name' => 'required',
        '12board_name' => 'required',
        '12passing_date' => 'required',
        '12course_type' => 'required',
        '12marks' => 'required',
    ]);
    $admissionform = $request->session()->get('admissionform');
    $admissionform = $request->all();
    $admissionform->save();

     return redirect('/front_office_desk/create-step3')
                    ->with('success','Product updated successfully');
}                 
}
```

Comment: Check this `$validatedData)` . Does laravel auto understand it? Else I guess you need to re-assign

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand why that ain't working either. Though from my understanding you are actually creating twice. But I guess a different approach would do:

1.) Don't store the whole instance of the AdmissionForm in session, just store the validated data

2.) Add  then when storing in the second case, merge these two arrays and save them as one:

```
/**
 * Post Request to store step1 info in session
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function postCreateStep1(Request $request)
{
    $validatedData = $request->validate([
        'name' => 'required',
        'dateOfBirth' => 'required',
        'contactNumber1' => 'required',
        'contactNumber2' => 'required',
        'email' => 'required',
        'reference' => 'required',
        'address' => 'required',
        'purpose_of_visit' => 'required',
        'intend_to_apply_for' => 'required',
        'any_applied_file_for_visa' => 'required',
        'acknowledgement' => 'required',
    ]);
    if(empty($request->session()->get('admissionform'))){

        $request->session()->put('admissionform',  $validatedData );

    }
    return redirect('/front_office_desk/create-step2')
                    ->with('success','Product updated successfully');
}   
public function postCreateStep2(Request $request)
{
     $request->validate([
        'specialization' => 'required',
        '12institute_name' => 'required',
        '12board_name' => 'required',
        '12passing_date' => 'required',
        '12course_type' => 'required',
        '12marks' => 'required',
    ]);
     $admissionform = $request->session()->get('admissionform');

     $data = array_merge(request()->all(), $admissionform));

     Admissionform::create($data);

     return redirect('/front_office_desk/create-step3')
                    ->with('success','Product updated successfully');
}
```

Comment: array_merge(): Expected parameter 2 to be an array, object given

Comment: in this line $data = array_merge(request()->all(), $admissionform);

Comment: seems like the `$admissionform` data coming in as an object. just convert it to array with `$admissionform->toArray()`